# Generate similar text based on category or the similar texts

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, text-generation, self-study

I'm trying to generate the similar text based on the category or to generate text by combining similar texts into the new text. I was checking multiple nlp tasks like question generation, but they don't work for my task.

I have a dataset of text and related categories. In addition, I have a text category classificatory

Is there any text generation branches for the similar tasks or the papers to read? I looked at Permgen, but I had a problem with generation

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can study this article and the links provided in it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_generation.

Answer (score 0):

You can fine-tune a pre-trained general-purpose language model (i.e. GPT-2, GPT-3) for each of your categories with the texts belonging to the category.